# Azure Notification Hubs REST API with PHP

Tags: php, azure, push-notification

I'm trying to create a SharedAccessSignature for the Azure Notifications Hubs API in PHP.

I keep getting the error  "Invalid authorization token signature".

Anyone has an example of creating the SAS in PHP 5.4+?
There is some documentation of the API on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170477.aspx, but some people say that the implementation differs from the documentation.

This is my failing implementation:

```
private static function get_authentication_header()
    {
        $uri = "https://x.servicebus.windows.net/x";
        $expiry = time() + (60*60);
        $string = utf8_encode(urlencode($uri) . "\n" . $expiry);
        $keyname = "DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature";
        $key = base64_decode(static::HUB_KEY);
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $string,  $key));
        $sas = 'SharedAccessSignature sig=' . $signature . '&se=' . $expiry . '&skn=' .      $keyname . '&sr=' . urlencode($uri);
        return $sas;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple wrapper to send notifications to Notification Hubs with PHP.

```
<?php

include 'Notification.php';

class NotificationHub {

    const API_VERSION = "?api-version=2013-10";

    private $endpoint;
    private $hubPath;
    private $sasKeyName;
    private $sasKeyValue;

    function __construct($connectionString, $hubPath) {
        $this->hubPath = $hubPath;

        $this->parseConnectionString($connectionString);
    }

    private function parseConnectionString($connectionString) {
        $parts = explode(";", $connectionString);
        if (sizeof($parts) != 3) {
            throw new Exception("Error parsing connection string: " . $connectionString);
        }

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (strpos($part, "Endpoint") === 0) {
                $this->endpoint = "https" . substr($part, 11);
            } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKeyName") === 0) {
                $this->sasKeyName = substr($part, 20);
            } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKey") === 0) {
                $this->sasKeyValue = substr($part, 16);
            }
        }
    }

    private function generateSasToken($uri) {
        $targetUri = strtolower(rawurlencode(strtolower($uri)));

        $expires = time();
        $expiresInMins = 60;
        $expires = $expires + $expiresInMins * 60;
        $toSign = $targetUri . "\n" . $expires;

        $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $this->sasKeyValue, TRUE)));

        $token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" . $targetUri . "&sig="
                    . $signature . "&se=" . $expires . "&skn=" . $this->sasKeyName;

        return $token;
    }

    public function broadcastNotification($notification) {
        $this->sendNotification($notification, "");
    }

    public function sendNotification($notification, $tagsOrTagExpression) {
        echo $tagsOrTagExpression."<p>";

        if (is_array($tagsOrTagExpression)) {
            $tagExpression = implode(" || ", $tagsOrTagExpression);
        } else {
            $tagExpression = $tagsOrTagExpression;
        }

        # build uri
        $uri = $this->endpoint . $this->hubPath . "/messages" . NotificationHub::API_VERSION;

        echo $uri."<p>";

        $ch = curl_init($uri);

        if (in_array($notification->format, ["template", "apple", "gcm"])) {
            $contentType = "application/json";
        } else {
            $contentType = "application/xml";
        }

        $token = $this->generateSasToken($uri);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: '.$token,
            'Content-Type: '.$contentType,
            'ServiceBusNotification-Format: '.$notification->format
        ];

        if ("" !== $tagExpression) {
            $headers[] = 'ServiceBusNotification-Tags: '.$tagExpression;
        }

        # add headers for other platforms
        if (is_array($notification->headers)) {
            $headers = array_merge($headers, $notification->headers);
        }

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $notification->payload
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        if ($info['http_code'] <> 201) {
            throw new Exception('Error sending notificaiton: '. $info['http_code'] . ' msg: ' . $response);
        }

        //print_r($info);

        //echo $response;
    } 
}

?>
```

I do not know if you wanted to send pushes or to do registration management. It is not hard to modify the above to do registration management as shown in the NH REST APIs (remember the order in the xml documents matters!): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223264.aspx.

Let me know if you still run into problems.

Elio

Comment: Hi Elio,

With your code, I was able to connect successfully to the Notification Hub API, getting an 201 response when submitting a push notification. But all my push notifications are not sent, but logged under the "all channell errors" metric in the azure control panel. Is it possible to include the notification.php file as well? Maybe I made a mistake with the specific headers or something.

Comment: Hi Elio, I'm still having problems with the Notification Hub API. Getting a 201 response is no problem, but no notifications get sent. Sending a notification with the DEBUG panel works. So it must be something with my notification payload or headers.

Comment: As of today everything seems to work with the same codebase, some internal problems with Azure Notification Hubs? Push for iOS and Windows Phone doing it great now.