# Is "2013-08" the latest Azure Notification Hubs REST API version or is the documentation outdated?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm wondering if the **`Azure Notification Hubs REST API`** [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx) is still correct and up-to-date or **if there is already a newer API version than "2013-08" that can be used**.

- All the single pages show "Updated: February 26, 2015", but I guess it was just a meta data update of all the pages, since the API version didn't change, it's still "2013-08".
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23410885/594074) (and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/notificationhubs-rest-php/NotificationHub.php)) is an example for the REST API usage from [Elio Damaggio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2048830/elio-damaggio) which uses "2013-10" as the api version.
- I tried all possible api version values in the format "yyyy-mm" from "2013-10" to "2015-03" and the following were working: "2013-10", "2014-01", "2014-05", "2014-08", "2014-09", "2015-01".

Does anyone use a newer API version than "2013-08" or does anyone know anything about a newer API version or documentation? **Specifically, does anyone know if there is a documentation for a newer API version, e.g. "2015-01", or at least a changelog?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an [answer on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3f0b7cff-c4f9-49aa-b7f9-742868adc457/is-201308-the-latest-rest-api-version-or-is-the-documentation-outdated):

> The latest version is 2015-01. All or most of features works with
>   starting version 2013-08.
>
> Version in documentation indicates that minimum version required for
>   working that feature. Hence, all documentation is pointing to 2013-08.
>
> ...
>
> Yes, you can use version 2015-01 instead of 2013-08. There won’t be
>   any difference because we didn’t do any breaking changes from 2013-08.
>   All the features works from version 2013-08.

Moreover, the source code for the *Java REST wrapper for Windows Azure Notification Hubs* [on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend) seems to be a good reference. It is using api version "2014-09", not "2015-01" right now, but at least it includes the registration code for *Amazon Device Messaging* and *Baidu Cloud Push* which are currently missing in the REST API documentation.